# php mysql (INSERT QUERY)

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple payment form and  it is include `voucher_id`, `customer_id`, `amount`, `payment_type`, `transaction_type` and `date`.

Transaction_type’s are withdrawls and deposits.

My data base table should not contain "amount" column. it has credit and debit column. In this case, I want to `INSERT`  amount to `debit` column if transaction `type ="Withdraws"`  of `INSERT` amount to credit column if `Transaction_type ="Deposits"`.

When I `INSERT` data to table show:

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Because, table has debit and credit column. But my form has one column and it is name is amount. How can INSERT this query to sort out my question.

```
<?php

// save data if form is submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){

        // catch data
        $voucher_numebr = $_POST['voucher_numebr'];
        $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $acc_type = $_POST['acc_type'];
        $payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
        $discription = $_POST['discription'];
        $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        // $balance = $_POST['balance'];

        $tranaction_type = $_POST['tranaction_type'];
        $balance="NOT DEFINE";

            //insert  to the tbl_customer_account


            if($tranaction_type == "Withdrawls."){
                //echo "1";
                $sql ='INSERT INTO tbl_customer_account VALUES(NULL,"'.$voucher_numebr.'","'.$member_id.'","'.$amount.'","'.$acc_type.'","'.$payment_type.'","'.$discription.'","'.$created.'","'.$tranaction_type.'","'.$balance.'")';

            }
            else{
                $sql ='INSERT INTO tbl_customer_account VALUES(NULL,"'.$voucher_numebr.'","'.$member_id.'","'.$amount.'","'.$acc_type.'","'.$payment_type.'","'.$discription.'","'.$created.'")';

            }

        //else{




        //}


        mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
        echo 'form submitted'; 
        echo '<br />';
        echo mysql_affected_rows(); die();

    }



?>
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Please help me.. This is my final project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not specifying a value for each column, you have to specify which columns you're updating. This is a good practice even when you are updating all columns, so you don't have to worry about future changes to the table's structure (e.g., adding or moving columns).

You haven't included the table structure, so I'll have to guess your column names:

```
        if($tranaction_type == "Withdrawls."){
            //echo "1";
            $sql ='INSERT INTO tbl_customer_account (some_field, voucher_number, member_id, debits, account_type, payment_type, description, created, transaction_type, balance) VALUES(NULL,"'.$voucher_numebr.'","'.$member_id.'","'.$amount.'","'.$acc_type.'","'.$payment_type.'","'.$discription.'","'.$created.'","'.$tranaction_type.'","'.$balance.'")';

        }
        else{
            $sql ='INSERT INTO tbl_customer_account (some_field, voucher_number, member_id, credits, account_type, payment_type, description, created) VALUES(NULL,"'.$voucher_numebr.'","'.$member_id.'","'.$amount.'","'.$acc_type.'","'.$payment_type.'","'.$discription.'","'.$created.'")';

        }
```

I suppose there's a reason you're leaving out `transaction_type` and `balance` for deposits?

Comment: yeah..acctually i never write INSERT query like this one.. i always use direct format..  i got that..shmosel, Thank you very much. i ve correct my error..

Answer (score 0):

`Column count doesn't match value count at row ...` means you have specified a different amount of columns than you have for values.

```
-- correct
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2');

-- error: 1 column, 2 values
INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'); 

-- error: 2 columns, 1 value
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1');
```

Check your query and fix it so the number of columns and values match.

Comment: In fact this is why you should always specify your columns :D

Comment: Seems like he's inserting an amount field into a table that has `credit` and `debit` columns. Would definitely help to see some code...

Comment: my form has text box and it is name is "amount". That amount will be insert to credit OR debit column in one time.. but table has debit AND credit column. therefor show this error.. column count does not match...

Comment: Can i know my concept is right? debit and credit records shulob be contain in one table.. is that okay?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the table structure, but it seems more natural to have a single column with positive or negative amounts.